# S&P P/E Ratio 2008 Spike Explanation

Tags: valuation

I'm looking at S&P PE ratio chart over time, and there is a large spike around 2008, and I'm trying to understand the reason for this change. Is it simply that earnings declined so sharply that P/E was quickly elevated?

For reference [this](http://www.macrotrends.net/2577/sp-500-pe-ratio-price-to-earnings-chart) is an example chart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bank earnings specifically, but yes.

http://www.macrotrends.net/1324/s-p-500-earnings-history